# Overwriting CreateHandle method in derived Control

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

Let we have a third party DLL that create a native window and return it handle.

I want to use this feature in C# WinForms application via MyControl class, which based on System.Windows.Forms.Control.

How to overwrite properly the virtual protected method Control.CreateHandle in class derived from Control?

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WinFormsApp {
  public class MyControl : Control {

    [DllImport("MyLib.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr CreateWindow();

    protected override void CreateHandle() {

      // Did to need do invoke a base.CreateHandle()?
      // However, it creates Control.Handle it self.

      var handle = CreateWindow();

      // How to associate returned handle with MyControl instance?

      (WindowTarget as NativeWindow)?.AssignHandle(handle);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.createhandle(v=vs.110).aspx) Notes to Inheritors:
When overriding CreateHandle in a derived class, be sure to call the base class's CreateHandle method to ensure that the handle is created.

Comment: I known about mentioned requirement. See comments in code template offered in my question.

Comment: I think for what you want to do, you may need to inherit `NativeWindow`. Please see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow(v=vs.110).aspx). But I could be wrong.